# Reverse engineering or Code from scratch

Tags: c, reverse-engineering

I got a project that is already developed, in other words I have an API for some software that coded in C language, but the company haven't the source code, thus my mission is to write the source code for this application. Now I have the executable program and I want to write the source code, regarding to my less experience I'm asking, which is better, to write the source code from the scratch or to use some reverse engineering tool to find out the source code? But notice that reverse engineering tools results with some hard to read files since there are not enough comments!

Comment: " but the company haven't the source code" - I wonder how that could happen?

Comment: @MitchWheat I guess is a not free lib/dll nad the company does not want to pay the licence...

Comment: Yes. I know..............

Comment: @mitch That's totally right.. it is not free

Comment: @MitchWheat I think is not illegal. It is simply: why I have to pay for something that I can do myself? Android docet...

Comment: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

No reverse-engineering tool will give you a source code (with or without the comments). So you can safely abandon this idea.

It is definitely better (in your case) to write new code from scratch using the existing executable as your black-box reference point.

Make sure to have *many* test cases that should cover as much of the original functionality as possible and when you are done writing your code run them all to affirm that your code is a reasonable replica of the original.

Comment: @ YePhlcK Actually i found a tool called "Retargetable Decompiler" which decompile the executable file, but as I have said, it is very hard to read. So what do you think.

Comment: Your "very hard to read" was exactly the reason I recommended you abandon the reverse engineering idea. Reverse engineering production code (which is often compiler-optimized) requires way higher skill level than writing a "similar" executable by observing the behavior of an existing one.